# How do I statically compile and use openssl/md5.h c++

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to use the md5 hashing function in openssl library in c++

I did download the openssl folder and referenced to include the location of the folder in "AdditionalIncludeDirectories" in my .vcxproj file. The compiler knows the functions exist, however, it is unable to link the functions.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    MD5_CTX md5;
    
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    MD5_Update(&md5, (const unsigned char *)test, hi.length());
    unsigned char buffer_md5[16];
    MD5_Final(buffer_md5, &md5);
    printf("Input: %s", hi);
    printf("\nMD5: ");
    char buf[32];
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "%02x", buffer_md5[i]);
        result.append(buf);
    }
    std::cout << "\nResult:" << result << endl;
```

However, I do see linker error. I do understand that this is because I have not linked any libraries. I want to understand how to create the libraries or if we can download and add it to the path and link it?

This is the error I am seeing

```
2>a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MD5_Update
2>a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MD5_Final
2>a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MD5_Init
```

Comment: OpenSSL is overkill if all you want to do is calculate an MD5 hash.  Have a nose around for something simpler.

Comment: Do you have an example , what other library could I use to calculate md5 hash using c++

Comment: research https://www.google.com/search?q=calculate+md5+hash+using+c%2B%2B | @edit for sure it shows other links https://gist.github.com/mfontanini/92a8b4a286c3dc42d432ce0956c25d71 . TBH there will be endless solutions on GitHub. https://github.com/CommanderBubble/MD5 https://github.com/teezoop/MD5 https://gist.github.com/RPiAwesomeness/1434a3589a979f508aa959ea329b5446 https://github.com/juzhong/MD5 https://github.com/stbrumme/hash-library You'll have trouble choosing.

Comment: that also redirects to using openssl

Comment: @KamilCuk this won't work for strings >64 characters.